# How to install a perl module without a dependency

Tags: windows, perl, perl-module

I've got a perl module (Email::AutoReply) which has BerkeleyDB listed in the README as an optional dependency. When you try to install it with cpan or cpanminus, it tries to install BerkeleyDB as well. The problem is that no matter what I do, BerkeleyDB fails to install with a long list of errors, even though I meet all the requirements. This is preventing me from installing Email::AutoReply, even though it's supposed to be an optional thing.

So, how do I install a module without one of it's dependencies? Can I remove the dependency somehow? Is there some command line option for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing the other [dependencies](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/AMONSEN/Email-AutoReply-1.04/Makefile.PL) (which you probably have done from your earlier attempts),

```
cd /tmp
wget http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/A/AM/AMONSEN/Email-AutoReply-1.04.tar.gz
tar xvzf Email-AutoReply-1.04.tar.gz
cd Email-AutoReply
perl Makefile.PL && make test && make install
cd ..
rm -rf Email-AutoReply
```

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned I'm using windows. I still attempted to run the two perl commands but the first gave this error: "Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1."